# Scala: Future, zip, and recover

Tags: scala, future

The following code compiles and works as expected...

```
def find1(selector: JsValue): Future[Seq[String]]
def find2(selector: JsValue): Future[Seq[String]]

find1(Json.obj("name" -> "Joe")) zip
find2(Json.obj("name" -> "Tim")) map { case (result1, result2) =>
  val result = result1 ++ result2
  ...
}
```

... but if I add `recover` to handle possible errors like this...

```
find1(Json.obj("name" -> "Joe")) zip
find2(Json.obj("name" -> "Tim")) map { case (result1, result2) =>
  val result = result1 ++ result2
  ...
}.recover { case e =>
  ...
}
```

... I always get the following error:

```
[error] /home/j3d/test/TestController.scala:558: missing parameter type for expanded function
[error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
[error] Expected type was: ?
[error]        find2(Json.obj("name" -> "Tim")) map { case (result1, result2) =>
[error]                                             ^
[error] one error found
```

I've tried to specify the types of `result1` and `result2` like this...

```
find1(Json.obj("name" -> "Joe")) zip
find2(Json.obj("name" -> "Tim")) map { case (result1: Seq[String], result2: Seq[String]) =>
  val result = result1 ++ result2
  ...
}.recover { case e =>
  ...
}
```

... but nothing changes, i.e. it only compiles without `recover`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the operator notation throughout.

```
find1(Json.obj("name" -> "Joe")) zip
find2(Json.obj("name" -> "Tim")) map { case (result1, result2) =>
   val result = result1 ++ result2
   ...
} recover { case e => // removed the '.' 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Surely we can come up with a better word than "point-free" to mean "calling a method without a dot"? This has nothing to do with _point-free_ style.